# How do I get warnings.warn to issue a warning and not ignore the line?

Tags: python, python-2.7, warnings, suppress-warnings

I'm trying to raise a `DeprecationWarning`, with a code snippet based on the example shown in the docs. http://docs.python.org/2/library/warnings.html#warnings.warn

Official

```
def deprecation(message):
    warnings.warn(message, DeprecationWarning, stacklevel=2)
```

Mine

```
import warnings
warnings.warn("This is a warnings.", DeprecationWarning, stacklevel=2) is None  # returns True
```

I've tried removing the stacklevel argument, setting it to negative, 0, 2 and 20000. The warning is always silently swallowed. It doesn't issue a warning or raise an exception. It just ignores the line and returns `None`. The docs doesn't mention the criteria for ignoring. Giving a message, makes warnings.warn correctly issue a `Userwarning.`

What can be causing this and how do I get warn to actually warn?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

From the docs:

> By default, Python installs several warning filters, which can be
>   overridden by the command-line options passed to -W and calls to
>   filterwarnings().
>
> - DeprecationWarning and PendingDeprecationWarning, and ImportWarning are ignored.
> - BytesWarning is ignored unless the -b option is given once or twice; in this case this warning is either printed (-b) or turned into
>     an exception (-bb).

By default, `DeprecationWarning` is ignored. You can change the filters using the following:

```
warnings.simplefilter('always', DeprecationWarning)
```

Now your warnings should be printed:

```
>>> import warnings
>>> warnings.simplefilter('always', DeprecationWarning)
>>> warnings.warn('test', DeprecationWarning)
/home/guest/.env/bin/ipython:1: DeprecationWarning: test
  #!/home/guest/.env/bin/python
```

Comment: I see. I'm not sure I agree with that decision to change it from being loud to non-loud in 2.7. Users should, by default, be told when things are changing so they don't get caught completely unaware. Thanks.

Comment: @Damgaard: users don't care, as long as it works. It's a warning for developers, who should be testing with `-W all` or `-W once` anyway.

Answer (score 9):

The warnings module implements filtering of warnings based on certain conditions.  You can show the default filters by printing `warnings.filters`:

```
$ python -c "import warnings; print(warnings.filters)"
[('ignore', None, <type 'exceptions.DeprecationWarning'>, None, 0),
 ('ignore', None, <type 'exceptions.PendingDeprecationWarning'>, None, 0),
 ('ignore', None, <type 'exceptions.ImportWarning'>, None, 0),
 ('ignore', None, <type 'exceptions.BytesWarning'>, None, 0)]
```

As you can see, `DeprecationWarning` is ignored by default.  You can use the functions in the [`warnings`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/warnings.html) module and the [`-W` command-line option](http://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-W) to Python to configure the filters -- see the documentation for details.

Example:

```
$ python -Wall
Python 2.7.3 (default, Sep 26 2013, 20:03:06) 
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import warnings
>>> warnings.warn("test", DeprecationWarning)
__main__:1: DeprecationWarning: test
```

Comment: Is there a way to programmatically turn on all warnings?  (e.g. not at commandline?)

Comment: @MarcelWilson Something like `warnings.simplefilter("always")` (or `warnings.simplefilter("default")`, if you only want to see the first occurrence of each warning).  Just read the `warnings` module documentation for details.

Answer (score -1):

```
$ python -Wall
Python 2.7.3 (default, Sep 26 2013, 20:03:06) 
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import warnings
>>> warnings.warn("test", DeprecationWarning)
__main__:1: DeprecationWarning: test
```