# Why does out of range numpy list slicing not raise IndexError

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

This is the shape of the array I'm using and I'm wondering why this doesn't result in an IndexError. The array result is just the same array.

```
import numpy as np
example = np.zeros((240, 320, 3))
example = example[-999:999,-999:999,:]
```

This holds for an example like this too:

```
x = np.array([[2,3,4],[3,4,5]])
a = x[-10:10,-10:10]
```

Since I'm relying on this raising an exception, it is confusing for me. Does numpy just index using the in bounds array and not the values that lay outside the range?

Comment: My best guess is that they try to keep the slice behaviour consistent with lists and other sequences, as shown in the dupe

Comment: you can use `np.arange(-999,1000,1)`. Slicing is "forgiving", indexing is not.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54632256/numpy-slicing-with-bound-checks