# Numpy: are bound checks necessary when slicing arrays

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, indexing

If you do e.g. the following:

```
a = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12], [13, 14, 15]])
print(a[2:10])
```

Python won't complain and prints the array as in `a[2:]` which would be great in my usecase. I want to loop through a large array and slice it into equally sized chunks until the array is "used up". The last array can thus be smaller than the rest which doesn't matter to me.

However: I'm concerned about security leaks, performance leaks, the possibility for this behaviour to become deprecated in the near future, etc.. Is it safe and intended to use slicing like this or should it be avoided and I have to go the extra mile to make sure the last chunk is sliced as `a[2:]` or `a[2:len(a)]`?

There are related Answers like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54632256/numpy-slicing-with-bound-checks) but I haven't found anything addressing my concerns

Comment: `numpy` inherited this behavior from Python lists (at least conceptually), and it's been standard behavior from the beginning.  There's no way you can index outside the bounds.  The main (only?) downside is that you may end up with an array that's smaller than expected, potentially even size 0 in the siced dimension.  But you are aware of that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Slice resolution is not done in numpy. [`slice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#slice) objects have a convenience method called `indices` method, which is only documented in the C API under [`PySlice_GetIndices`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/slice.html#c.PySlice_GetIndices). In fact the python documentation states that they have no functionality besides storing indices.

When you run `a[2:10]`, the slice object is `slice(2, 10)`, and the length of the axis is `a.shape[0] == 5`:

```
>>> slice(2, 10).indices(5)
(2, 5, 1)
```

This is builtin python behavior, at a lower level than numpy. The linked question has an example of getting an error for the corresponding index:

```
>>> a[np.arange(2, 10)]
```

In this case, the passed object is not a slice, so it *does* get handled by numpy, and raises an error:

```
IndexError: index 5 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 5
```

This is the same error that you would get if you tried accessing the invalid index individually:

```
>>> a[5]
...
IndexError: index 5 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 5
```

Incidentally, python lists and tuples will check the bounds on a scalar index as well:

```
>>> a.tolist()[5]
...
IndexError: list index out of range
```

You can implement your own bounds checking, for example to create a fancy index using `slice.indices`:

```
>>> a[np.arange(*slice(2, 10).indices(a.shape[0]))]
array([[ 7,  8,  9],
       [10, 11, 12],
       [13, 14, 15]])
```

Comment: Thank you for the in depth answer. As I will only use a[x:y] for indexing, everything will only be handled via slice objects, right? So I assume I don't need bounds checking (see comment below question)

Comment: @Pinko. That's pretty much correct. The checking will be implemented under the hood for you via `slice`