# How to prevent accidental assignment into empty NumPy views

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, slice

Consider the following Python + NumPy code that executes without error:

```py
a = np.array((1, 2, 3))

a[13:17] = 23
```

Using a slice beyond the limits of the array truncates the slice and even returns an empty view if start and stop are beyond the limits. Assigning to such a slice just drops the input.

In my use case the indices are calculated in a non-trivial way and are used to manipulate selected parts of an array. The above behavior means that I might silently skip parts of that manipultion if the indices are miscalculated. That can be hard to detect and can lead to "almost correct" results, i.e. the worst kind of programming errors.

For that reason I'd like to have strict checking for slices so that a start or stop outside the array bounds triggers an error. Is there a way to enable that in NumPy?

As additional information, the arrays are large and the operation is performed very often, i.e. there should be no performance penalty. Furthermore, the arrays are often multidimensional, including multidimensional slicing.

Comment: You can write a wrapper class for the NumPy array that performs the desired check in the `__getitem__` and `__setitem__` methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on how complicated your indices are (read: how much pain in the backside it is to predict shapes after slicing), you may want to compute the expected shape directly and then `reshape` to it. If the size of your actual sliced array doesn't match this will raise an error. Overhead is minor:

```
import numpy as np
from timeit import timeit


def use_reshape(a,idx,val):
    expected_shape = ((s.stop-s.start-1)//(s.step or 1) + 1 if isinstance(s,slice) else 1 for s in idx)
    a[idx].reshape(*expected_shape)[...] = val

def no_check(a,idx,val):
    a[idx] = val
    
val = 23
idx = np.s_[13:1000:2,14:20]
for f in (no_check,use_reshape):
    a = np.zeros((1000,1000))
    print(f.__name__)
    print(timeit(lambda:f(a,idx,val),number=1000),'ms')
    assert (a[idx] == val).all()
    
# check it works
print("\nThis should raise an exception:\n")
use_reshape(a,np.s_[1000:1001,10],0)
```

Please note, that this is proof of concept code. To make it safe you'd have to check for unexpected index kinds, matching numbers of dimensions and, importantly, check for indices that select a single element.

Running it anyway:

```
no_check
0.004587646995787509 ms
use_reshape
0.006306983006652445 ms

This should raise an exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "check.py", line 22, in <module>
    use_reshape(a,np.s_[1000:1001,10],0)
  File "check.py", line 7, in use_reshape
    a[idx].reshape(*expected_shape)[...] = val
ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 0 into shape (1,1)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I've raised an Issue at NumPy: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/19831

Answer (score 2):

You could be using [`np.put_along_axis`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.put_along_axis.html?highlight=put_along_axis#numpy.put_along_axis) instead, which seems to fit your needs:

```
>>> a = np.array((1, 2, 3))
>>> np.put_along_axis(a, indices=np.arange(13, 17), axis=0, values=23)
```

The above will raise the following error:

> **IndexError**: index `13` is out of bounds for axis `0` with size `3`

Parameter `values` can either be a scalar value or another NumPy array.

Or in a shorter form:

```
>>> np.put_along_axis(a, np.r_[13:17], 23, 0)
```

---

*Edit:* Alternatively [`np.put`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.put.html) has a `mode='raise'` option (which is set by default):

> ***`np.put(a, ind, v, mode='raise')`***
>
> - `a`: *ndarray* - Target array.
> - `ind`: *array_like* - Target indices, interpreted as integers.
> - `v`: *array_like* - Values to place in a at target indices. [...]
> - `mode: {'raise', 'wrap', 'clip'}` *optional* - Specifies how out-of-bounds
>   indices will behave.
>
>   - 'raise' – raise an error (default)
>   - 'wrap' – wrap around
>   - 'clip' – clip to the range

The default behavior will be:

```
>>> np.put(a, np.r_[13:17], 23)
```

> **IndexError**: index `13` is out of bounds for axis `0` with size `3`

while with `mode='clip'`, it remains silent:

```
 >>> np.put(a, np.r_[13:17], 23, mode='clip')
```

Comment: Interesting, thank you! Both versions calculate index arrays and get a bit complicated for multidimensional arrays. I'll clarify the question accordingly.

Comment: A quick performance comparison showed that `np.put_along_axis()` is about 10x slower and `np.put()` is about 40x slower than assigning to the slice the normal way.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54632256/numpy-slicing-with-bound-checks) is related?

Comment: I've raised an Issue at NumPy: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/19831

Answer (score 1):

One way to achieve the behavior you want is to use ranges instead of slices:

```
a = np.array((1, 2, 3))
a[np.arange(13, 17)] = 23
```

I think NumPy's behavior here is consistent with the behavior of pure Python's lists and should be expected. Instead of workarounds, it might be better for code readability to explicitly add asserts:

```
index_1, index_2 = ... # a complex computation
assert index_1 < index_2 and index_2 < a.shape[0]
a[index_1:index_2] = 23
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I've raised an Issue at NumPy: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/19831