# How to throw DeprecationWarning when users are importing a module?

Tags: python, module, warnings

So I looked for a bit but I wasn't finding anything that talked about my issue, so I decided to open a new question.

My question is, how can I throw a DeprecationError in python if a user were to import a module that has been renamed?

Quick Example of what I would be trying to accomplish:

```
>>> import foo.bar as foobar
DeprecationWarning: import foo.bar is deprecated and will be removed in a 
future release, please use import foo.bar2 in order to access the goodness 
of foo bar
```

I tried to something like this in the bar file (for this example):

**bar.py**

```
import stuff

warnings.warn("import foo.bar is deprecated and will be removed in a future release, please use import foo.bar2 in order to access the goodness of foo bar", DeprecationWarning)
```

But unfortunately this did not work when I ran a test script and imported the module. Is there something that I am missing? How can I run the code in the module on loading of the module?

Comment: See [this article](https://www.lesinskis.com/python_deprecation_tutorial.html). You need to start the interpreter with the `-Wd` flag, or set the filter: `warnings.simplefilter('default')`

Comment: Might be due to DeprecationWarning being ignored by default. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20960110/how-do-i-get-warnings-warn-to-issue-a-warning-and-not-ignore-the-line) may answer your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set out a filter for the warnings or use -Wd switch with interpreter call. By default the  deprecuation warnings are switched off.

See an example at http://www.jaggedverge.com/2016/09/deprecation-warnings-in-python/

Comment: So this may be situational, but it seems (based on this article) that deprecation warnings in general shouldn't be displayed to the users? So if a feature has been changed do you eventually remove it or do you leave it for the users? I'm just a bit confused as to how that works.

Comment: I think it helps distinguishing isuue of a warning (always controlled by your module) and displaying the message called 'filter' (usually controlled by a user). As for broader question - changing the interface of the program is bad, but you can do it once in a while. Depretiation warning should allow users migrate to new interface, while old one still there, but I think you cannot control too much with these warnings and simply deliever a new interface at some version (raising exceptions on wrong call).